# Pago ou pagado?

Tags: verbos, conjugações

Qual dessas duas formas está correta? (verbo "pagar", não tenho certeza do tempo verbal)

> Eu achei que você já tinha pago a conta.

ou:

> Eu achei que você já tinha pagado a conta.

Isso sempre me confunde. Tenho *quase* certeza que a primeira forma está certa, mas a segunda também me parece plausível. Seria uma daquelas situações que admitem duas formas distintas? Ou uma delas está de fato incorreta?

P.S. Contraste: "a conta foi paga" está correto, mas "a conta foi pagada" soa estranho e tenho razoável certeza de que está incorreto. Minha dúvida está no uso em conjunto com o verbo "ter".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Verbos de duplo particípio**

Muitos verbos admitem no particípio duas formas, **uma regular e outra irregular**. Em alguns, uma delas caiu em desuso completo ou quase completo, ficando muitas como simples adjetivos - e.g. completo, confesso, anexo.  **Quando os dois particípios se conservam, usa-se o regular com os verbos auxiliares "ter" ou "haver" e o irregular com os auxiliares "ser" ou "estar".**

exemplos:

- tinha expulsado - foi expulso
- tinha aceitado  - foi aceito
- tinha matado    - foi morto
- tinha soltado   - foi solto
- tinha salvado   - foi salvo
- tinha limpado   - foi limpo
- tinha gastado   - foi gasto

**Respondendo à sua pergunta, no Brasil, com o auxiliar ter usamos as duas formas de particípio: *tinha pagado/pago*. Mas com ser, usamos apenas *foi pago.***

Comment: Acho que já se falou anteriormente disto aqui no pt.SE: curiosamente, em Portugal usamos "aceite" em vez de "aceito"... uma irregularidade entre as irregularidades.

Comment: Aqui temos uma boa explicação [link](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI41386,41046-Pago)

Answer (score 13):

Ambas as formas estão corretas. A regra geral é que a forma regular se usa para os tempos verbais compostos (com "ter" ou "haver") e que a forma irregular se usa onde ocorre adjetivo e em orações passivas (com o verbo *ser*, mas também num sentido lato com *estar*, *andar*, *viver* — passivas estativas —, *ficar* ­— passivas resultativas). Portanto:

> Eu achei que você já tinha pagado a conta.

mas

> Eu achava que a conta já estava paga.
>   Eu acho que a conta já foi paga.

Contudo, pelo menos em Portugal, *pagado* é muito raro e *pago* serve para os dois casos. O CETEMPúblico tem apenas uma entrada para *pagado* e até é como adjetivo. O [LX Conjugator](http://lxcenter.di.fc.ul.pt/services/pt/LXServicesConjugatorPT.html) mostra apenas *pago* como particípio passado de *pagar*. O Priberam [mostra](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/pagar) ambas, tal como o [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da Língua Portuguesa](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=43188&highlight=pagar) oficial.

Está [resposta do Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagado-ganhado-e-gastado-participios-em-desuso/32645) apresenta a opinião de diversas obras de referência sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

O uso das duas formas do particípio para esses verbos ditos *abundantes* já foi muito bem explicado nas respostas de [Artefacto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1403/2764) e [Centaurus](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1404/2764), além de ser descrito em diversos sites, como o [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/imprimido-ou-impresso/) — mas vale fazer umas pequenas adições e conectar essa pergunta a outras relacionadas no site.

O [Clube do Português](https://www.clubedoportugues.com.br/impresso-imprimido/), por exemplo, observa que:

> Cintra e Cunha destacam que, quando usamos o verbo imprimir no sentido de “produzir movimento” ou “infundir”, somente é permitido o uso do **particípio regular** (**imprimido**), independentemente de a frase estar na voz ativa ou passiva.
>
> Ex: **Foi imprimida** enorme velocidade no carro.
>
> Ex: Com a crise, **foi imprimido** um movimento de mudança na sociedade

E lembra também:

> particípios irregulares podem ser usados como **adjetivo** e **substantivo**. É o que ocorre com o termo impresso.
>
> Nesses casos, é possível haver variação de gênero e de número. Veja:
> Ex: Aquilo estava escrito em papeis impressos. (adjetivo)
> Ex: O texto estava escrito em folhas impressas. (adjetivo)
> Ex: Os impressos foram enviados para a editora. (substantivo)

E, por último, é importante estar ciente de que, embora ambos "pago" e "pagado" estejam certamente corretos (no momento), não há acordo entre os gramáticos e outros conhecedores da língua sobre os *verbos abundantes* em geral — assunto tratado na pergunta: [Usar os dois particípios regular e/ou irregular é correto?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5433/2764).

Answer (score -1):

"Pagado" está incorreto "Pago" está correto, **no português de Portugal**.

> Dizer: Este telemóvel está pagado.
> ou: Este telemóvel foi pagado.
> ou: Este telemóvel tem sido pagado.

#### Estão todas incorretas!

A forma correta é:

> Este telemóvel está **pago**.
> Este telemóvel foi **pago**.
> Este telemóvel tem sido **pago**.

"Pagado" nunca é utilizado no português europeu correto.

O mesmo acontece para os outros verbos: **sempre** expulso; aceito; morto; solto; salvo; limpo; gasto.

Comment: Estou procurando referências, se eu encontrar alguma eu volto atrás na resposta aceita. Mas até o momento não encontrei nada que relacionasse o acordo ortográfico com os verbos de duplo particípio. De todo modo, você percebe que todos os seus exemplos usam o verbo "ser", enquanto na pergunta eu usei o verbo "ter", certo? (ex.: "não sabia que ela tinha matado o marido" - não vejo aqui como se encaixaria "morto")

Comment: eu usaria nos seus exemplos: ter sido pago; ter sido morto; ter sido salvo, etc. para mim encaixa assim: não sabia que ela tinha morto o marido. eu ouo e utilizo essa expressão. acredite que se perguntar a um professor deportuguês eles lhe dirão o mesmo. eu falo o que ouço e me ensinaram

Comment: Esses grande ignorantes como José Saramago: https://books.google.nl/books?id=F2ZfAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Jos%C3%A9+Saramago%22+%22pagado%22&dq=inauthor:%22Jos%C3%A9+Saramago%22+%22pagado%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y

Comment: Duas referências (https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-participios-passados-de-pagar-gastar-e-ganhar/32626 e https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-os-participios-regulares-ganhado-pagado-e-gastado/23988) indicam que "pagado" terá caído em desuso.

Comment: praticamente todas as pessoas usam 'pagado' mas acredito que o correto  português diz 'pago'. vindo de fontes de conhecimentos superiores ao meu. pois imposto pela nova gramática

Comment: @JNat a resposta do ciberduvidas que mais bem fundamentada é esta: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagado-ganhado-e-gastado-participios-em-desuso/32645 . Conclusão: "pagado" é de facto raro (aliás eu digo-o na minha resposta), mas daí a incorreto e próprio de "pessoas ignorantes e mal-faladas" vai uma grande distância.

Comment: @JNat "cair em desuso" não torna uma forma incorreta, torna? Tivesse ela caído em desuso em um país/região mas não em outro, como ficaria? Reiterando, se surgir uma evidência que "pagado" está de fato incorreto (seja segundo o acordo ortográfico ou alguma outra norma vigente), eu mudo prontamente a resposta aceita, mas sem isso ainda considero que ambas as formas são aceitáveis (cada uma acompanhada do verbo apropriado, é claro - "pagado" com "ter" e "haver", "pago" com "ser" e "estar"). P.S. Eu nunca prestei atenção se *outras pessoas* falam isso aqui no Brasil ou não, vou começar a prestar.

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges Que interessante, então vocês usam o mesmo particípio pra ["matar"](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-matar) e ["morrer"](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-morrer)! Suponho que como o primeiro é transitivo direto e o segundo é intransitivo, não há ambiguidade. No Brasil usamos "matado" e "morrido" sempre, com o verbo "ter" (com "ser', naturalmente, usamos "morto").

Comment: @mgibsonbr É a mesma coisa em Portugal: ter morrido, ter matado, ser morto.

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim. "O assassino não devia ter morto o presidente." é uma frase aceite. Claro, que também se diz: "O assassino que matou o presidente não o devia ter feito."

Comment: "Eu achei que tinhas pagado a conta" ou "Eu achei que tinhas pago a conta" estão ambas corretas em pt_PT.

Comment: Não é a forma mais correta. Pelo menos é o que os meus professores formados em língua portuguesa me ensinaram... todos os verbos que tenham a mesma forma que 'pago' são os mais corretos. Até porque se observarmos com atenção vimos que pago parece mais um atributo ao nome, ou seja, "conta está paga" conta está como? paga. E se os meus professores não estão corretos então o sistema de ensino vai mal... Porque não devem ensinar a matéria mal

Comment: Numa discussão a sério, como a que queremos ter aqui, dizer  "os meus professores disseram-me" tem pouco peso. O que conta são fontes públicas que todos possam verificar. A respeito de matar, vê o dicionário online da [Porto Editora](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/matar): particípio passado de matar é *matado* ou *morto*. Este artigo de um [gramático no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/matado-e-morto/176) esclarece que se usa *matado* com os verbos *ter* e *haver*, e *morto* com *ser* e *estar*.

Comment: A internet nem sempre é viável e nem sempre está atualizada.

Comment: É verdade, toda a gente se pode enganar. Mas ninguém aqui vai acreditar que o dicionário online da Porto Editora e o [dicionáro Priberam online](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/matar) e o gramático da Ciberdúvidas estão todos enganados só por que tu insistes que tu e os teus professores é que sabem. Tu ou eu ou qualquer outra pessoa. Um posição aqui neste site só é levada a sério se for fundamenta em fonte publicada que possa ser verificada por quem quiser fazê-lo.

Comment: Não me tento impor, simplesmente dar a minha opinião