# Construção da Voz Passiva/Passive Voice Construction

Tags: diferenças, voz-passiva, pronomes-reflexivos, forma-verbal

### In English

The passive voice is an important part of any language (at least the ones I know). Now, I know that there are two ways to form the passive voice in Portuguese. One of them parallels English exactly, whereas the other one is a foreign concept to any native English speaker (like myself). These can be seen below:

**Ser + Past Participle**

> 1. Esse tipo de comportamento não **é visto** em toda a terra!
> 2. Essas palavras **foram ditas** para animar-nos.
> 3. Muita gente **foi morta** na guerra há cinco anos atrás.

**Use of the Reflexive**

> 1. Esse tipo de comportamento não **se vê** em toda a terra!
> 2. **Disseram-se** essas palavras para animar-nos.
> 3. **Matou-se** muita gente na guerra há cinco anos atrás.

Thus, my questions are:

- Which form is preferred
- Is it possible to form reflexively the passive voice with ANY word, including those which already use a reflexive pronoun (such as *lembrar-se*), or is it only limited to certain words? Thus, does "*lembra-se o carro*" carry the same meaning as "*o carro é lembrado*", if the context were to call for it?

Thanks for your responses in advance.

---

### Em Português

A voz passiva é uma característica importante de todas as línguas de que tenho conhecimento. Já sei que há duas maneiras que podem ser usadas para criar a voz passiva. Uma delas é similar à sua homóloga inglesa, mas a outra é complicada para os que são falantes nativos de inglês (como eu). Podem ser vistas abaixo:

**Ser + Particípio Passado**

> 1. Esse tipo de comportamento não **é visto** em toda a terra!
> 2. Essas palavras **foram ditas** para animar-nos.
> 3. Muita gente **foi morta** na guerra há cinco anos atrás.

**Com a Construção Reflexiva**

> 1. Esse tipo de comportamento não **se vê** em toda a terra!
> 2. **Disseram-se** essas palavras para animar-nos.
> 3. **Matou-se** muita gente na guerra há cinco anos atrás.

Portanto, queria fazer duas perguntas:

- Qual dessas é preferida?
- Será que é possível formar a voz passiva com qualquer verbo, incluindo os que já usam um pronome reflexivo (tal como o verbo "lembrar-se")? Ou em vez disso, existem limites? Quero dizer, será que "*lembra-se o carro*" pode significar a mesma coisa como "*o carro é lembrado*", em certos contextos?

Estou ansioso pelas suas boas respostas.

---

*Esta é a minha primeira pergunta em Português. Assim, indique-me quaisquer erros gramaticais, se fizer favor.*

Comment: That's a very good first posting in Portuguese, Mr Chasi. I like your question because the impersonal "half-passives" formed using *se* have no good direct analogue in English yet are as common as can be in Portuguese. Detailed answers to this question might include how apparently equivalent forms are "blocked" from use, like *matou-se muita gente* instead of *foi matada*, perhaps because they have too reflexive a sense otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist thanks! Yes, it was very difficult for me to get used to this 'half-passives' concept. And I see what you mean, because "matou-se muita gente", might give the impression that people killed themselves (committed suicide)

Comment: Mr Chasi, Your first sentence "(Nós) nâo vemos esse tipo de comportamento por aqui." can be put into the passive voice as  "Esse tipo de comportamento não é visto por aqui" (the agent "por nós", is usually omitted)  "Não se vê esse tipo de comportamento por aqui."  is grammatical and current usage but it isn't your first sentence in the passive voice.   "Lembra-se o carro" makes no sense to me.  Maybe you mean "Tu te lembras daquele carro?" ou "lembras-te do carro que João dirigia?"   "O carro é lembrado" sounds weird but is not wrong.  It  may fit a certain context.

Comment: @tchrist  We don't say "muita gente foi matada" but we can say "muita gente foi morta".  We can also say "matou-se muita gente", of course.  The problem here is a verb with double participle.  see http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/pago-ou-pagado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RESPOSTA CURTA**

This is a heck of a troublesome question! Eis dois exemplos típicos de voz passiva analítica (**VPA**) e voz passiva sintética (**VPS**, nome mais usual do que voz passiva reflexa):

> (VPA) Estas casas todas que estão a ver ***foram construídas*** na última década.
>
> (VPS) ***Construíram-se*** trezentas mil casas na última década.

Nem todos os usos seguem este padrão, mas esta é a tendência. A VPA enfatiza o sujeito, e este está claramente definido (estas casas todas que estão a ver). A VPS dá mais ênfase ao verbo, e o sujeito oficial da frase (trezentas mil casas) não está tão claramente definido: nós não sabemos quais são essas casas. Mais ainda, tipicamente, os falantes nativos interpretam a VPS, não como voz passiva, mas sim como voz ativa com o sujeito não identificado: pessoas, empresas não identificadas construíram casas.

***RESPOSTA LONGA***

A chamada VPS, pode ser complicada até mesmo para os falantes nativos. A complicação resulta do seguinte: A gramática tradicional (**GT**), baseada em critérios formais e históricos, ensina a VPS como voz passiva, enquanto os falantes nativos entendem-na, na maioria dos casos, como voz ativa. Vamos primeiro à GT, para depois vermos uma maneira alternativa, mais simples, de entender as coisas.

**Voz Passiva Sintética (VPS) na Gramática Tradicional**

A voz passiva só é possível com verbos transitivos diretos, como *beber*: o objeto direto na voz ativa (**VA**), *vinho* no exemplo seguinte, passa a sujeito na voz passiva analítica (**VPA**) e na chamada voz passiva sintética (**VPS**):

> (a – VA) Em Portugal, muita gente bebe vinho.
>
> (b – VPA) Em Portugal, vinho é bebido (por muita gente).
>
> (c – VPS) Em Portugal, bebe-se vinho.

Se o verbo admitir conjugações reflexas e não reflexas, a VPS é ambígua, como no teu exemplo “matou-se muita gente:” não se sabe se muita gente se matou a si mesma ou se foi morta por outras pessoas. A VPA não sofre dessa ambiguidade. Passa-se o mesmo com *lembrar*, que também admite conjugações reflexas e não reflexas. Com o carro não há problema, mas com uma pessoa é diferente. Por exemplo, “lembra-se o João” pode significar “o João é lembrado” (isto é, alguém pensa no João, a única possibilidade no caso do carro, ou alguém diz ao João para ele não se esquecer de alguma coisa) ou ainda “o João lembra-se (de alguma coisa)”.

Com verbos intransitivos ou transitivos indiretos a voz passiva não é possível. Mas existe um construção parecida com a VPS que é possível. Vejamos um exemplo com o verbo transitivo indireto *gostar*:

> (d) Em Portugal, muita gente gosta de vinho.
>
> (e) Em Portugal, gosta-se de vinho.

A frase (e) é uma construção com voz ativa: o sujeito está indeterminado (a palavra ***se*** designa-se por partícula indeterminante do sujeito) e *vinho* é objeto indireto. Significa mais ou menos o mesmo que (d): há pessoas em Portugal que gostam de vinho. As frases (c) e (e) são muito parecidas. Como podemos distinguir a VPS da **VA** com **s**ujeito **i**ndeterminado ***se*** (**VASI**)? Temos duas maneiras. Se o verbo for transitivo direto, a frase é VPS; se for intransitivo ou transitivo indireto é VASI. A outra maneira é ver se é possível reescrever a frase como VPA: se for, como (c), que se pode reescrever como (b), a frase é VPS; se não for, como em (e) (não se pode dizer **vinho é gostado*), a frase é VASI. Depois há ainda o plural. Em ambas as construções o verbo está na terceira pessoa. Mas na VPS, concorda em número com o sujeito oficial da frase; na VASI, fica sempre no singular:

> (f – VPS) Em Portugal, bebem-se muitos vinhos diferentes.
>
> (g – VASI) Em Portugal, gosta-se de muitos vinhos diferentes.

Compreende-se portanto que até os falantes nativos tenham dificuldades com a VPS e a VASI. Porquê *bebem-se muitos vinhos* e não *bebe-se muito vinhos*? E porquê *gosta-se de muitos vinhos* e não *gostam-se de muitos vinhos* A resposta da gramática tradicional é que *vinhos* é sujeito em (f), logo *bebem-se* porque o verbo concorda com *vinhos*; e é objeto indireto em (g), logo o verbo não tem que concordar com *vinhos*.

**Compreensão Intuitiva da Chamada Voz Passiva Sintética**

Só que a classificação da GT é meramente formal, e não é assim que os falantes entendem estas frases. Isso torna-se mais óbvio se pusermos alguns dos exemplos acima lado a lado:

> Em Portugal, (e) gosta-se de vinho, (c) bebe-se vinho.

Para o falante nativo, *vinho* não é sujeito em (c) e objeto em (e), como diz a GT: é objeto em ambas; ambas as frases estão na voz ativa, e em ambas o sujeito está indeterminado. É como dizer em inglês, “In Portugal, people like wine, people drink wine”, em que o sujeito, *people*, também está indeterminado. Do mesmo modo:

> Foi um belo dia: (f1) foi-se à praia, (f2) tomou-se um banho, (f3) comeu-se uma sardinhada, (f4) falou-se das últimas novidades.

Na GT, (f1) é VASI; (f2) é VPS com sujeito *um banho*; (f3) é também VPS com sujeito *uma sardinhada*; e (f4) é de novo VASI. Mas o falante nativo imagina o mesmo sujeito indeterminado em todas as orações: um grupo de pessoas (em que quase de certeza ele se inclui) que foi à praia e fez todas aquelas coisas. Depois no plural, por causa da artificialidade da distinção entre VPS e VASI, muitos falantes nativos não se importam de dizer coisas como:

> Foi um belo dia: (g1) foi-se à praia; (g2) deu-se uns mergulhos; (g3) comeu-se umas sardinhas; (g4) falou-se das últimas novidades.

De acordo com a GT, (g4) está correta, mas (g2) e (g3) estão erradas. A GT prescreve:

> Foi um belo dia: (g1) foi-se à praia; (g2a) deram-se uns mergulhos; (g3a) comeram-se umas sardinhas; (g4) falou-se das últimas novidades.

É claro que isto não entra bem nem mesmo na cabeça do falante nativo, e já motivou esta questão sobre [vende-se casas ou vendem-se casas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/210/%C3%89-errado-dizer-vende-se-casas).

Apesar de oficialmente na GT *mergulhos* e *sardinhas* serem os sujeitos das respetivas orações, eles aprecem depois do verbo, que é uma posição pouco comum para um sujeito no português (na intuição, eles são objetos diretos, e estão na posição normal). E frequentemente não é possível colocá-los antes do verbo: “mergulhos deram-se” sugere que os mergulhos se ofereceram a alguém; “sardinhas comeram-se” sugere que as sardinhas se canibalizaram. É esta posição adiantada do verbo na VPS/VASI que enfatiza o verbo. Portanto a escolha entre VPS e VPA (a VPA não é alternativa à VASI) depende do que se quer enfatizar. Por exemplo na frase anterior poder-se-ia reescrever as orações VPS como VPA:

> Foi um belo dia: (g1) foi-se à praia; (g2b) uns mergulhos foram dados; (g3b) umas sardinhas foram comidas; (g4) falou-se das últimas novidades.

Mas (g2b) e (g3b), soam estranhíssimos, tal como soariam em inglês “a few dives were made, a few sardines were eaten.” A tradução mais natural seria com voz ativa: “we had a few dives and ate sardines,” ou talvez “one had a few dives and ate sardines,” porque o que se quer realçar é que alguém (oficialmente não identificado, mas neste exemplo compreende-se quem é) se divertiu a dar mergulhos e a comer sardinhas. O exemplo (b) acima, *vinho é bebido*, tal como “wine is drunk in Portugal,” também é estranho, enquanto as versões (a) e (c), que realçam a ação, são mais naturais. A tradução mais natural de (c) é “people drink wine in Portugal.”

Existem construções VPA perfeitamente naturais com *mergulhos* e *sardinhas*, em que se quer realçar os mergulhos e as sardinhas. As versões VPS correspondentes normalmente não são naturais.

> (h1) Este mergulho foi executado na perfeição; (h2) (nada natural) executou-se este mergulho na perfeição.
>
> (i1) A sardinhada foi muito elogiada; (i2) (natural, mas menos que a VPA) elogiou-se muito a sardinhada.
>
> (j1) Estes vinhos foram produzidos na nossa quinta; (j2) (pouco natural) produziram-se estes vinhos na nossa quinta.
>
> (k1) Estas casas foram construídas em 2005; (k2) (pouco natural) Construíram-se estas casas em 2005.

Eu esperaria ouvir (h1) numa competição de mergulho. (h2) não é natural: ou se diz, “o atleta executou o mergulho na perfeição” ou se vai para a VPA. (i1) e (i2) são ambas naturais, com (i2) a pôr mais ênfase na ação e no próprio sujeito indeterminado. Já no teu exemplo 1, as duas versões são equivalentes. “Não se vê” soa bem apesar de o verbo vir depois do “comportamento.” Não sei explicar porquê. Talvez por “ver-se” ser relativamente idiomático e ser interpretado como *existe*.

> (1a) Este tipo de comportamento não é visto em toda a terra; (1b) este tipo de comportamento não se vê em toda a terra.

Ambas são interpretadas como “este tipo de comportamento não existe em toda a terra.” Mas se anteciparmos o verbo, o que é mais natural na VPS que na VPA, a ênfase passe para o verbo: “não se vê este tipo de comportamento (…);” o que pode ser interpretado como “não temos oportunidade de ver este tipo de comportamento em toda a terra.” Nos teus exemplos (2), a VPA põe o foco nas palavras independentemente de quem as disse. A VPS, eu só a usaria se as palavras não tivessem sido ditos diretamente a nós; caso contrário diria, “disseram-nos essas palavras…” que é voz ativa, mas com o sujeito omisso.

Andei a ver o uso da VPA e VPS neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), e há uma tendência para se usar a VPA quando o sujeito está bem identificado, tipicamente incluindo artigo definido, e o foco da atenção está no sujeito:

> (l) O carro ***foi encontrado*** abandonado numa rua em Botafogo. (Luiz Alfredo Garcia-Roza, *O Silêncio da Chuva*, 1996.)
>
> (m) O prédio ***foi construído*** em 1795 por escravos e ***ocupado*** mais tarde pelo general Bento Gonçalves e por Garibaldi. (Litoral e Interior têm programas, 16-4-1997)
>
> (n) O Museu de História Natural e o Museu de História da Arte de Viena ***foram construídos*** na cidade de Viena, no estilo da Renascença Italiana, sob a direção dos arquitetos Carl Hasenauer e Gottfried Semper, ***tendo sido concluída*** a construção em 1881. (Enc.)

Seria possível usar a VPS nestas frases. Em (l) o sentido não altera, mas seria menos natural usar a VPS. Em (m) a VPS exigiria substituir “por escravos” (o agente da passiva que a VPS modernamente não tem) por “com trabalho escravo,” mas o sentido alterava-se: a ênfase iria para a construção, por exemplo, “construiu-se o prédio com trabalho escravo” por oposição a “com trabalho livre”. Em (n) a VPS também alteraria o sentido, mudando o foco para a construção, e o facto de ela ter sido feita em Viena e não noutro sítio.
Já com a VPS, o sujeito, na ótica da GT ou objeto direto na intuição, é menos bem individualizado. O foco está na atividade. Incluo também um caso VASI.

> (o) [E]m São Paulo ***comeu-se*** muito pão de trigo da terra. (Júlio Ribeiro, *A Carne*)
>
> (p) ***Bebeu-se*** champagne, à saúde das damas (Fialho d’Almeida, *A Cidade do Vício*, 1943.)
>
> (q) Portanto ***comeu-se e bebeu-se*** (VASI) até alta noite. (Joaquim Manuel de Macedo, *Os Dois Amores*)

Se mudássemos a VPS em (o) para VPA o sentido alterava-se: em vez de o foco estar no que se come em São Paulo, passaria a estar no pão de trigo da terra (que era comido em São Paulo por oposição a ser comido noutro sítio. Em (p) a VPA seria muito estranha: com a VPA seria “***o*** champagne foi bebido,” e estaríamos a explicar o que aconteceu ao champagne em vez focar no que as pessoas (não identificadas) fizeram. Em (q) a VPA é impossível.
Os dois exemplos seguintes de VPS são um pouco diferentes

> (r) Os segredos ***fizeram-se*** para ser contados. (João Rio, *Dentro da Noite*, 1910)
>
> (s) Peço-te o obséquio especial de não frequentares a janela. As janelas ***fizeram-se*** para alumiar as casas, e arejá-las, ***não se fizeram*** para ter senhoras penduradas. (Ramalho Ortigão, *Cartas a Emília*, 1888.)

Não é óbvio para mim que os sujeitos oficiais da VPS sejam neste caso interpretados intuitivamente como objetos diretos feitos por um sujeito não identificado, ao contrário de todos os exemplos de VPS que vimos até agora. Outra possibilidade é entendermos que os segredos e as janelas metaforicamente se fizeram a si mesmos. Mas também não estou certo disto. Talvez o melhor seja interpretar *X fez-se para* como uma expressão idiomática com o significado de *a função de X é*. Note-se que, inusitadamente, *os segredos* e *as janelas* precedem o verbo. Nestes casos a VPA teria exatamente o mesmo significado que a VPS.

Comment: Jacinto, sei que foi apenas um exemplo mas "Em Portugal, vinho é bebido" soa artificial.  Nesse caso, "bebe-se vinho" soa mais natural.  Mas se acrescentarmos um complemento, e.g. "Em Portugal o vinho verde é bebido preferencialmente neste tipo de taça." então soa natural. É apenas uma constatação.

Comment: Acho que no Brasil ninguém diria "Em Portugal gosta-se vinho".  Nem mesmo com uma preposição ("gosta-se de vinho") ainda não seria o natural.  Eu diria "Em Portugal aprecia-se um bom vinho".

Comment: Mais uma coisa (e isso já está sendo discutido em outra questão) "Os segredos fizeram-se para ser contados"  Poderia ser "para serem contados"?

Comment: @Centaurus Muitos destes exemplos são de facto artificiais. Uns foi de propósito, para mostrar que a VPS e a VPA não são equivalentes. Lá mais para baixo na resposta eu digo isso mesmo, *bebe-se vinho* é natural, *vinho é bebido* é estranho. Outros também foi de propósito, para conseguir aquelas justaposições para expor a arbitrariedade da gramática tradicional neste ponto. *Em Portugal gosta-se de vinho* escapa, serve o meu propósito.

Comment: @Centaurus, Sim a resposta do Artefacto é isso que diz, a escolha entre *para ser contados* ou *para serem contados é uma questão de estilo e o que se quer realçar.

Comment: A tua discussão descarrilha um bocado quando chegas ao (g2b). Começas a tirar conclusões sobre a adequação de VPS/VPA, quando a diferença é mais a ordem das palavras. "Uns mergulhos foram dados" não é uma boa frase, mais aquela mais perto de "deram-se uns mergulhos" é "foram dados uns mergulhos", que já não soa tão mal (esp. se se adicionar qq coisa), embora o significado seja diferente (pouco há de passiva em "deram-se uns mergulhos"). Mas "deram-se uns mergulhos em condições perigosas"/"foram dados uns mergulhos em condições perigosas" parecem-me mais ou menos equivalentes em significado.

Comment: E os teus exemplos finais e a estrofe de Camões com um agente da passiva, que incluí na minha resposta, sugerem que não possamos dizer taxativamente que a passiva sintética é de facto um sujeito indeterminado encapotado em todas as situações.

Comment: I'm sorry that it took so long to respond. This is a fantastic answer, thanks. It very clearly answers all-but-one of my queries (or maybe I missed it in your answer). I was just wondering whether it is so that there are particular verbs which are 'reserved' (as it were), and thus can not be used in the passive voice context? Should I just make it a practice not to use the passive voice with verbs which are already used reflexively?

Comment: Two things. (1) you can use the passive only with verbs that admit a direct object. (2) Of these, if they can be used reflexively they are potentialy  ambiguous in the passiva sintética, as with *matou-se, lembrou-se o João*. *Lembrou-se o carro* is not ambiguous, because a carro is not able to lembrar, can only be lembrado. I mention this already. I'll try and make it clearer.

Comment: I see it now, you mean cases like, *o João diverte-se*? Yes, you'd better not use the passiva here. *O João e divertido por ele mesmo* sounds weird. As for the SPS, in this case you cannot really tell whether *o João diverte-se* or *diverte-se o João* is passive or active, because the subjet and object is the same anyway. Everybody understands it as active though.

Comment: @Jacinto Great, that's all the clarification I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacinto Fiz uma pequenas alterações (como incluir o "de" em "Em Portugal, (e) gosta-se de vinho, (c) bebe-se vinho.", a que o Centaurus se referiu em 2015). Se foi em erro, por favor desfaça.

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar, as tuas frases 2. e 3. não são completamente análogas:

> 2a. Essas palavras foram ditas para animar-nos.
>   2b. Disseram-se essas palavras para animar-nos.

A palavra no início da frase tem um maior ênfase, portanto em (2a) o foco está mais nas palavras, enquanto em (2b) no ato de dizê-las. Em ambos os casos se pode alterar a ordem:

> 2c. Foram ditas essas palavras para animar-nos.
>   2d. Essas palavras disseram-se para animar-nos.

No entanto é mais comum fazer a inversão sujeito-predicado com a passiva sintética. Nem (2c), nem (2d) soam particularmente bem, especialmente (2d). Parte da razão será talvez que a passiva sintética se confunde com uma construção com sujeito indeterminado, como em:

> 2f. Disse-se essas palavras para animar-nos.

Neste caso, temos de ler "essas palavras" como objeto direto, cuja posição normal é após o verbo. A questão é que a fronteira entre um *se* apassavidor e um *se* sujeito indeterminado é muito ténue. Por exemplo, a tua frase 3 é ambígua:

> 3b. Matou-se muita gente na guerra há cinco anos atrás.

Podemos lê-la como:

> 3c. [As pessoas] Mataram muito gente na guerra há cinco anos. [sujeito indeterminado]
>   3d. Muita gente foi morta na guerra há cinco anos. [passiva sintética]

e diria até que leitura preferida é 3c.

A outra parte da razão é que o foco com a *passiva* é geralmente **o sujeito** (objeto na voz ativa), enquanto com a *passiva sintética* é **a ação**.

Em termos de significado, tenho dificuldade em encontrar diferenças entre os pares (2a)/(2d) e (2b)/(2c).

Em geral, outra diferença é o facto de que, em português moderno, é muito incomum incluir um agente da passiva com a passiva sintética:

> *2e. Disseram-se essas palavras pelos anfitriãos para animar-nos.

Este tipo de construção pode contudo ser encontrada em autores mais antigos (*Os Lusíadas*, VII, 55):

> «Tempo cedo virá que outras vitórias
>   Estas, que agora olhais, abaterão.
>   Aqui se escreverão novas histórias
>   **Por gentes estrangeiras que virão**;

Perguntar qual é a mais utilizada não é muito útil, já que as duas formas têm valores algo diferentes.

Por fim, a tua pergunta sobre se há restrições no uso da passiva sintética com alguns verbos (pronominais ou reflexos).

Quando o significado pretendido é de facto o reflexivo, não faz sentido falar em voz passiva, porque a voz a reflexiva já indica que o facto expresso pelo verbo foi *praticado* (como na voz ativa) e *sofrido* (como na passiva) pelo sujeito. Com verbos pronominais, não me ocorre nenhum que aceite um objeto direto.

No caso de verbos opcionalmente pronominais ou reflexivos, será de evitar a passiva sintética na medida em que podem surgir ambiguidades. O teu exemplo com "lembrar" não é muito bom porque lembrar também se usa de forma não pronominal (com apenas pequenas diferenças de significado). Mas considera a frase (3b). Esta também pode ser lida como "muita gente suicidou-se", embora isso implicasse uma inversão sujeito-predicado que seria incomum. Por outro lado, se reescrevêssemos:

> 3d. Muita gente matou-se na guerra há cinco anos.

Então praticamente a única leitura possível é que muita gente se suicidou, caso contrário teríamos uma ordem indireta semelhante a (2d), que como disse é rara. Para complicar ainda mais, podíamos escrever:

> 3e. Muita gente se matou na guerra há cinco anos!...

e aí uma leitura com significado de (3c)/(3d) já seria provável (dependendo do contexto, claro), porque a ordem indireta de sujeito-predicado é acompanhada por uma próclise típica de frases exclamativas.

Comment: A tua frase 2f já é aceite nas gramáticas? Segundo o que consultei, ela não é VPS porque o verbo não concorda com o sujeito; e não é voz ativa com sujeito indetermindado porque essa construção não é gramatical com verbos transitivos diretos (o que eu acho um tremendo disparate).

Comment: @Jacinto Pelo menos o CIberduvidas  [admite (citando um artigo)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/voz-passiva-sintetica-de-novo/10332). [Esta resposta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/verbo-volitivo--se-apassivanteindeterminado/21492) diz "temos explicado aqui que há bons argumentos para apoiar a existência de um se indeterminado associado com um verbo no singular, mesmo que o tópico da frase esteja no plural", embora o link não vá para o sítio correto.

Comment: Pois, a questão é que tudo o que vi diz que a construção com o ***se*** indeterminante do sujeito não admite verbos transitivos diretos, como *dizer*. Mas os exemplos deles também usam transitivos diretos. Vou ter que lhes *colocar uma questão*.