# Significado da particula "se"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, morfologia

Tenho algumas duvidas referentes ao uso do **se** que listei abaixo.

- Na minha leitura de *O Cortiço* de Aluízio Azevedo recentemente, um dos trechos que me estranharam foi este:

> Em todo o caso vamos seguindo, resolveu Jerônimo, impaciente, nem
>   **se** temesse que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito.

O trecho faz parte do dialogo contido neste [link](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:O_corti%C3%A7o.djvu/249). Gostaria que me respondessem qual é o sentido e a classificação morfossintática da partícula **se** no trecho.

Segunda questão:
- Durante minha pesquisa para entender as variedades de **se** eu percebi uma ambiguidade que pode ser sintetizada na seguinte frase:

> Levantou-se Joaquim.

**Se** é partícula apassivadora, ou é pronome reflexivo? Se a minha analise esta correta, ambas servem, pois poderia se tratar de alguém levantando a si mesmo, ou da forma passiva sintética equivalente a forma passiva analítica:

> Joaquim foi levantado (voz passiva analítica)

Talvez poderia até mesmo ser partícula expletiva, mas não tenho certeza.

Espero ter sido claro em minhas questões.

---

Acho que não fui claro em relação a ter mais de uma pergunta com apenas o uso do **se** em comum. Talvez em devesse ter postado a segunda em outra questão.

Comment: Chris, isto são duas perguntas independentes. Então é melhor postar duas perguntas separadas: apaga a das orações subordinadas aqui e abre uma segunda pergunta. Já agora, facilitaria se desses um ou dois exemplos de orações que achas que estão nessa zona nebulosa entre a causal e condicional. No caso do *Cortiço* do A. Azevedo, eu diria que o *se* é conjunção; mas nunca vi aquela construção antes.

Comment: Joaquim foi levantado -> Levantou-se o Joaquim. Mesmo assim, o usual é Levantaram o Joaquim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### O *se* d’*O Cortiço* é conjunção

Esta construção frásica d’*O Cortiço* não é de uso corrente. Eu nunca a tinha encontrado, e procurando neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) e no Google Books não encontro outra igual. Para mim a frase só tem sentido se interpretarmos ***se*** como conjunção e ***nem se*** forma uma locução conjuntiva comparativa; no fundo houve aqui a elisão de algo como *como não estaria:*

> (a) “resolveu Jerónimo, impaciente, [como não estaria] **nem se** temesse que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito.”

Podemos ainda parafraseá-la em:

> (b) resolveu Jerónimo, impaciente; **nem se** temesse que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito, ele estaria tão impaciente
>
> (c) resolveu Jerónimo, **mais** impaciente **do que (estaria) se** temesse que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito

Esta é também a interpretação que encontrei em [*Notas de Português de Filinto e Odorico,* 1955, de Martins de Aguiar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KllTAAAAMAAJ&q=Tamb%C3%A9m%20se%20emprega%20nem%20se%20e%20o%20cruzamento%20das%20duas%20express%C3%B5es&dq=Tamb%C3%A9m%20se%20emprega%20nem%20se%20e%20o%20cruzamento%20das%20duas%20express%C3%B5es&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXmtHMl6vUAhVCmBoKHZPpCOQQ6AEIJTAA), que identifica como equivalentes as locuções ***nem se, nem que*** e ***nem que se*** ([segundo excerto para completar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KllTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22nem%20se%20temesse%22&dq=%22nem%20se%20temesse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNqLT6lqvUAhVCiRoKHXp4CFsQ6AEILzAB); grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> […] *grunhia D. Cochino* [um porco] *pela estrada, de tal modo, como não grunhiria **nem que** cem magarefes* [açougueiros] *o acossassem.* Também se emprega ***nem se*** e o cruzamento das duas expressões, ***nem que se:***
> “Em todo o caso vamos seguindo, resolveu Jeronymo, impaciente, ***nem se*** temesse que a noite lhe fugisse de subito.” (Aloísio de Azevedo, “O Cortiço”, pág. 243.)

O primeiro exemplo da *Notas de Português* (“*como não grunhiria nem que cem magarefes o acossassem*…”) tem a mesma estrutura que (a) acima (*como não estaria nem se temesse*…), com *nem que* em vez de *nem se*, e é uma paráfrase de [*Fábulas de J. La Fontaine*, 1815, traduzidas por Francisco Manoel do Nascimento;](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EejqAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA95&lpg=RA1-PA95&dq=%22nem%20que%20cem%20magarefes%22&source=bl&ots=cZYXP7zfq9&sig=Ahw9xB0jZ2NtS6yVOFj2gSOqSgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9zfHKx6vUAhUCzRQKHeHSAnkQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22nem%20que%20cem%20magarefes%22&f=false) o original tem a mesma estrutura que a frase d’*O Cortiço*

> Grunhia Dom Cochino, pela estrada,
> **Nem que** cem magarefes o acossassem:

---

### Os outros *ses* não funcionam neste contexto

***Se*** é de facto também partícula apassivadora na voz passiva sintética (e pronome indeterminador do sujeito numa construção aparentada; vê [estas pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-voz-passiva-passive-voice-construction)) e pronome reflexo, como nos teus exemplos do Joaquim. Mas nenhum desses *ses* faz sentido no trecho d’*O Cortiço*. Se fosse partícula apassivadora, a frase seria equivalente a:

> (d) nem fosse temido que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito

Seria estranho usar a passiva, quando a questão é se o Jerónimo teme ou não. Mas a dificuldade maior nesta frase é que precisaríamos de qualquer coisa para ligar *nem* a *fosse* (ou a *se temesse* na frase original); teria de ser *nem se fosse* ou *nem que fosse* (*nem que se temesse* ou *nem se se temesse* na frase original). O *se* apassivador seria possível, mas noutro contexto:

> Recomendaram que não se confiasse que a noite esperasse por eles, nem se temesse que a noite lhes fugisse de súbito.

O pronome reflexo é impossível. Neste caso, *se* seria o objeto direto de *temer*—Jerónimo teme-se a si mesmo. Mas o objeto direto de *temer* é a oração substantiva *que a noite lhe fugisse de súbito*. Há ainda o *se* inerente da conjugação pronominal, que pode à primeira vista confundir-se com a conjugação reflexa (ao contrario da conjugação reflexa, na pronominal a ação não incide sobre o sujeito; e.g. *ele riu-se*). *Temer* admite conjugação pronominal. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) dá o exemplo “*o heroico soldado que da morte não se teme*”. Seria possível dizer:

> Receou-se que Jerónimo se temesse (de) que a noite lhe fugisse.

A preposição *de* é frequentemente omitida nestes casos. Mas há também nesta interpretação o problema de ligar na frase original o *nem* ao *se temesse*, se o este *se* fosse inerente ao verbo e não a conjunção *se*.

Comment: Daí você vê o que é um serviço bem feito! +1

Comment: Impressionante a resposta!

Comment: Os exemplos do Joaquim coloquei porque tinha outra questão em mente relacionada ao "se" usado daquele modo. Não os via como possibilidades.

Comment: Ah! @chris, eu pensei precisamente que estavas a explorar possibilidades para o *se* d'*O Cortiço*. Não sei a minha resposta responde satisfatoriamente à tua segunda pergunta? Realmente a tua pergunta original deveria ter sido três perguntas separadas.

Answer (score 0):

Essa construção permite ambas interpretações, a depender do contexto em que se insira a frase.

Nessa construção, tanto pode ser pronome reflexiva, como em

> Após seu tombo, *levantou-se Joaquim* (ou seja, Joaquim levantou a si mesmo)

como também pode ser partícula apassivadora, como em

> Após uma rápida avaliação dos candidatos disponíveis, *levantou-se Joaquim* (ou seja, o nome de Joaquim foi levantado por outras pessoas)

Comment: Marcelo, poderias detalhar melhor sua resposta ou adicionar referências à mesma para que fique claro o porquê da construção permitir ambas interpretações?

Comment: Perdão pela excessiva brevidade

Comment: Nos exemplos do Joaquim *se* pode ser, como dizes, interpretado como partícula apassivadora ou pronome reflexo. Mas não consigo compreender, e tu não explicas, como é que esses *ses* funcionariam no trecho d'*O Cortiço*, que é o cerne da questão.

Comment: Acho que a confusão causada aqui é minha culpa, por ter postado duas questões juntas. Em relação a sua resposta, seriam interessantes fontes.

Comment: Uma apostila minha (que não é uma fonte confiável e não prove uma explicação suficiente) resolve a ambiguidade, citada na segunda questão, dizendo que a posição em que o verbo esta é a característica que define, ou seja:
Levantou-se Joaquim (partícula apassivadora).
Joaquim levantou-se (pronome reflexivo).

Comment: @Chris, poderias considerar tirar a segunda pergunta daqui e repostá-la como pergunta separada, incluindo esse teu último comentário. Imagino que o Marcelo não se importaria (ele poderia sempre apagar esta resposta aqui e repostá-la) mas ele o dirá. O padrão que descreves, da posição do verbo, poderá ser o mais comum (no caso da passiva não tenho a certeza); mas o oposto pode ocorrer também: *as leis fizeram-se para se cumprirem* (passiva). Mas na prática, ambiguidades raramente ocorrem; o contexto clarifica a interpretação.