# Usar os dois particípios regular e/ou irregular é correto?

Tags: verbos, conjugações

Segundo sei, normalmente, o particípio passado regular deve ser usado com os verbos ter e haver, e o irregular com os verbos ser e estar, entre outros. Embora haja exceções que sempre só usaram um dos dois particípios...

Mas, pelo que tenho visto, parece que algumas formas acabaram por cair em desuso como é o caso do verbo pagar:

> Apesar de **ter pagado** a conta, a luz foi cortada.
>
> Mas a conta da luz **foi paga**.

Parece que, para cada verbo, hoje em dia, só se usa uma das formas.

Então a minha pergunta é se será correto usar os particípios segundo a regra que citei acima?

*Não seria a hora de deixar cair essa «regra»?*

Comment: Alguns verbos ainda detêm o particípio irregular., assunto já abordado em: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/pago-ou-pagado/1404?s=1|25.2298#1404   Quanto a "Não seria a hora de deixar cair essa «regra»?"  qualquer resposta seria simplesmente "opinião".

Answer (score 2):

A grande maioria dos verbos só têm uma forma, a regular. Pegando os verbos que você usa na sua pergunta:

*Saber, dever, usar, ter, haver, ser, estar, cortar, parecer, deixar* e *cair* têm todos apenas a forma regular. E, tendo apenas uma forma, a regra de " usar o particípio passado regular com os verbos ter e haver, e o irregular com os verbos ser e estar" é inaplicável. Isso vale provavelmente para mais de 90% dos verbos da língua portuguesa, embora eu não tenha feito nenhuma pesquisa para confirmar esse chute.

Uma pequena minoria de verbos, como *pagar*, têm uma forma irregular, ao lado da regular. Na sua maioria, eles seguem a regra que você cita: "particípio passado regular com ter e haver, e o irregular com ser e estar". Mas há casos, como o próprio *pagar*, ou *pegar*, em que muitos falantes não têm firmeza quanto à existência de duas formas. E aí ocorrem oscilações como "apesar de ter pago a conta". Mas muitos outros verbos são consensuais para a grande maioria dos falantes, como por exemplo *morrer*: não se usa nem "se ele houvesse morto" nem "ele está morrido", então não é possível dizer que a regra tenha caído em desuso.

(E, para completar, outra minoria, talvez ainda menor, que inclui por exemplo *ver* e seus derivados, tem apenas uma forma, mas essa é irregular (no caso, *visto*, *revisto*, etc.), e evidentemente, não se enquadra na regra que você questiona.)

---

O stafusa levanta uma questão importante: a distinção entre particípio e adjetivo. No caso, ele diz que em *ele foi morto*, "morto" não é o particípio de "morrer", mas o adjetivo "morto" (como em *sentei no toco de uma árvore morta*, por exemplo). O que está de acordo com o estranho fato de que o "particípio irregular" de morrer é igual ao de "matar" (quando uma pessoa morre, ou é "matada", ela fica... morta). Me convenci logo disso, mas já não tenho tanta certeza. Uma coisa visível é que no caso, "morto" flexiona em gênero: *ele foi morto*, *ela foi morta*. Mas me ocorre que essa é a regra quando usamos os verbo "ser" ou "estar": o particípio do verbo principal - se é que é um particípio - flexiona em gênero (e número), ao contrário do que acontece quando o auxiliar é "ter" ou "haver", mesmo quando o verbo principal tem apenas uma forma no particípio:

> *Tenho lido muitos romances* vs * *Tenho lidas muitas novelas*, evidentemente agramatical.
>
> *O livro está lido, agora é fazer o resumo* mas *a tese está lida, agora é fazer o resumo*.

Então não tenho mais certeza. Quando o auxiliar é "ser" ou "estar", não temos o particípio, e sim o adjetivo (que flexiona em gênero, ao contrário das formas verbais)? Mas, nesse caso, "ser" ou "estar" não são auxiliares, e sim verbos de ligação (não é a análise da gramática tradicional). Ou o particípio flexiona em gênero em alguns casos, mas não em outros?

Comment: Curioso, eu achava que a maioria tinha as duas formas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eles são chamados "abundantes", o que talvez contribua para a confusão, mas a abundância aí é a de particípios, não a de verbos...

Comment: Eu diria que no exemplo "Ele está morrido." temos o adjetivo "morto", não um verbo; de forma que um exemplo melhor no contexto seria, e.g., "Ele foi morrido.".

Comment: @stafusa Obrigado, editei a resposta de acordo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Este site, http://www.cartaforense.com.br/conteudo/colunas/onze-mil-verbos/15394 , diz que há cerca de 11 mil verbos em português. Não creio que os abundantes cheguem a uma centena (este outro site, http://radames.manosso.nom.br/linguagem/gramatica/morfologia/verbos-abundantes/ , lista 55 verbos abundantes, afirmando que são "todos". Lista também 167 verbos que têm apenas a forma irregular). De maneira que, sim, os verbos que só tëm o particípio regular são a grande maioria (bem mais que 90%, algo como 98%).

Comment: @JorgeB. Por outro lado, eu estava enganado: os verbos que só tem a forma irregular são em maior número que os verbos abundantes (embora o site inclua aí alguns verbos, como "substituir", cuja única "irregularidade" no particípio é o acento agudo: "substituído"). Tem a ver, acho, com o fato de que muitos destes verbos compõem subparadigmas ("ver" e derivados, "pôr" e derivados, por exemplo).

Comment: Um outro exemplo de verbo em que as duas formas são sempre usadas seguindo a regra é *acender*. Ninguém dirá "ele tinha aceso a lâmpada" muito menos "a lâmpada foi acendida". Será sempre "ele tinha acendido a lâmpada" e "a lâmpada foi acesa".

Answer (score 2):

Re:

> será correto usar os particípios segundo a regra que citei acima [*particípio passado regular deve ser usado com os verbos ter e haver, e o irregular com os verbos ser e estar*]?
>
> **Não seria a hora de deixar cair essa «regra»?**

**Não, a regra não desapareceu totalmente.**

A observação de que o uso simultâneo das duas formas tem caído em desuso é correta, mas este processo não está completo.

Duas ótimas discussões a respeito podem ser encontradas numa postagem no [Migalhas](https://www.migalhas.com.br/coluna/gramatigalhas/199283/pegar) e numa resposta no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pagado-ganhado-e-gastado-participios-em-desuso/32645#), que reproduzo abaixo:

##### Migalhas:

> ##### Pegar
>
> *José Maria da Costa*
> quarta-feira, 16 de abril de 2014
> Atualizado em 5 de outubro de 2022 16:00
>
> A leitora **Cíntia Pereira** envia a seguinte mensagem ao **Gramatigalhas**:
>
> "E quanto ao verbo pegar; o correto é dizer 'tinha pego' ou 'tinha pegado'?"
>
> ---
>
> **1)** Na lição de Luiz Antônio Sacconi, "o verbo pegar é abundante na língua familiar; não o é na língua culta".
>
> **2)** Pasquale Cipro Neto e Ulisses Infante lecionam que esse verbo, na língua culta, apresenta apenas o particípio passado regular (pegado).
>
> **3)** Antonio Henriques, de igual modo, preconiza pegado como a "única forma aceitável do particípio passado de pegar".
>
> **4)** Silveira Bueno preconiza a continuidade de existência e a possibilidade de uso normal de ambos os particípios - pegado e pego - de acordo com as regras previstas para os verbos abundantes no particípio: "com os verbos ter e haver usamos o particípio longo, invariável... Com os verbos ser e estar usamos o particípio breve, variável".
>
> **5)** Na lição de Vitório Bergo, o particípio passado regular (pegado) é "forma correta, usada pelos clássicos em vez de pego, que é moderna, e nos diversos sentidos usuais, como seguro, medrado, rente, etc.".
>
> **6)** Para Cândido de Oliveira, "ganho, gasto, pago, pego são usados indiferentemente para ambas as vozes (com qualquer auxiliar)", e "os particípios ganhado, gastado, pagado, pegado tendem a desaparecer".
>
> **7)** Em outra obra escrita com Regina Toledo Damião, anota Antonio Henriques que, "apesar do uso corrente da forma pego, ainda sobrevive entre bons autores a forma pegado" na atualidade.
>
> **8)** Para Sousa e Silva, que invoca a autoridade de Eduardo Carlos Pereira e de José Oiticica, pego "é um dos particípios de pegar (o outro é pegado), desconhecido, talvez, em Portugal, mas comuníssimo no Brasil".
>
> **9)** Domingos Paschoal Cegalla assim resume a questão da sintaxe desse verbo, no que tange ao uso de seu particípio passado: a) Pegado "se usa com os verbos ter e haver" (Homens da vizinhança tinham (ou haviam) pegado o animal); b) Pego é "forma contrata de pegado" e "se usa, de regra, com os verbos ser e estar" (O cão foi pego pelos moradores da vizinhança - O animal estava pego); c) "Há tendência para se usar pego na forma ativa" (Um morador vizinho tinha (ou havia) pego o animal).
>
> **10)** Ante a divergência apresentada entre os gramáticos, podem-se extrair as seguintes conclusões, de integral validade para o usuário da norma culta: a) o verbo pegar é abundante, assim na língua familiar como na língua culta, apresentando os dois particípios passados - pegado e pego; b) com tais particípios, o normal é seguir as regras previstas para os verbos abundantes e usar pegado com os verbos ter e haver, e pego com os verbos ser e estar; c) empregar, todavia, pego com os auxiliares ter e haver não pode ser considerado um erro; d) se pegado tende a desaparecer, o certo é que ainda existe e é usado em nosso idioma nos dias de hoje.
>
> **11)** Ultime-se com a anotação de que a pronúncia do particípio passado irregular pego é fechada (ê), e não aberta (é), como alguns teimam em dizer, até porque pego "com a vogal e aberta é forma do verbo pegar (eu pego)".

##### Ciberdúvidas:

> #### Pagado, ganhado e gastado: particípios em desuso?
>
> *Pelo visto, estou ultrapassado. Aprendi há muito que **pagado** é um arcaísmo, embora o Saramago, talvez por influência do castelhano, do catalão ou do valenciano, o use com frequência nas suas obras. Quanto a o **gastado** e o **ganhado** terem [dado o lugar](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-participios-passados-de-pagar-gastar-e-ganhar/32626) a **gasto** e a **ganho**, também quando usados com o verbo ter, confesso-me surpreendido. Passou a ser norma? E as formas **gastado** e **ganhado** são alternativas às simplificadas, quando usadas com o verbo ter, ou já ganharam o estatuto de arcaísmos?*
>
> *A seguir, virá a aceitação da palavra “empregue”, que já vi num dicionário, e a da palavra  “encarregue”, que ainda não vi em nenhum.*
>
> Miguel Faria de Bastos — Jurista — Lisboa, Portugal
>
> ---
>
> Do ponto de vista normativo, o uso dos particípios passados **gastado** e **ganhado** é correto e faz-se de maneira igual à de outros particípios regulares, isto é, ocorrendo só com o auxiliar **ter**. Com o auxiliar **ser**, o particípio passado tem sempre forma curta ou irregular (**gasto** e **ganho**).
>
> No entanto, há muito que certos gramáticos vêm assinalando a preferência do uso pelas formas irregulares destes particípios passados, mesmo em associação com o auxiliar ter («tinha gasto/ganho»):
>
> – [Vasco Botelho de Amaral](https://porticodalinguaportuguesa.pt/index.php/publicacoes/artigos/item/vasco-botelho-de-amaral-2), no *Grande Dicionário de Dificuldades e Subtilezas da Língua Portuguesa* (1958), observa que **ganhado** «vai rareando», e **gastado**, também.
>
> – Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, 1984, pág.440) consideram que pagado foi substituído por **pago**, e **ganhado** com **gastado** tendem a ser substituídos pelas formas irregulares.
>
> – Em obras exclusivamente elaboradas por gramáticos brasileiros, as posições podem não coincidir completamente: E. Bechara (*Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*, 2002, págs. 229/230) inclui **ganhado**, **gasto** e até mesmo **pagado** ao lado das formas curtas numa lista de formas participiais duplas, mas deixa indicação de estas formas irregulares poderem usar-se tanto na passiva como nos tempos compostos. Maria Helena de Moura Neves (Guia de Uso do Português, 2003), procurando conciliar a tradição normativa com a observação do uso por meio de corpora, apresenta **ganhado** e **gastado** como formas pouco usadas.
>
> – Na *Gramática do Português (GP)* da [Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian](https://gulbenkian.pt/) (vol. II, 2013, p. 1490) considera-se que Cunha e Cintra (1984) são demasiado taxativos sobre o uso de **pagado**, **ganhado** e **gastado**, porque, apesar de haver alguma preferência pelos particípios curtos nos tempos compostos, há falantes que veem como correta a ocorrência de particípios regulares nesses contextos (a perspetiva da GP apoia-se nos juízos dos falantes, não sendo porém coincidente com a gramática prescritiva, porque esta se fundamenta apenas no uso dos bons autores para definir regras e critérios).
>
> Refira-se que uma consulta do [Corpus de Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp) (Mark Davies e Michael Ferreira) confirma o escasso uso de **ganhado** e **gastado** em textos do séc. XX.
>
> Em suma, os particípios regulares aqui referidos são considerados corretos entre os gramáticos com preocupações normativas, mas alguns entre estes não deixam de frisar que se trata de formas pouco usadas. Seja como for, em contexto escolar, por exemplo, numa situação de exame, nenhuma destas formas estaria errada: «tinha ganhado»/«tinhas ganho», «tinha gastado»/«tinha gasto».
>
> Finalmente, apesar de os mais puristas os considerarem errados*, a verdade é que o particípio passado **empregue** ocorre na descrição gramatical há já algum tempo; por exemplo, Bechara (2002) diz que é forma recente, característica do português de Portugal). E mesmo encarregue, constantemente condenado pela norma mais conservador**, também já é mencionado pelo *Dicionário Houaiss*, desde a 1.ª edição, de 2001, mais uma vez, como forma usada em Portugal.
>
> <sub>* Cf. [Porquê encarregado, e não "encarregue"?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-encarregado-e-nao-encarregue/30635)</sub>
>
> <sub>** **Encarregue** não é aceite, porque o particípio passado de **carregar**, verbo donde deriva [encarregar](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/pergunta.php?id=30400), é carregado, e não *"carregue". A forma em causa, de origem popular, terá sido motivada pela analogia com [entregue](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-o-desaconselhado-participio-passado-encarregue/19746), particípio passado irregular de **entregar**, mas não são de excluir razões eufónicas e semânticas para o pouco apreço de encarregue entre os mais ciosos da elegância na expressão: com efeito, **encarregue** evoca **carregue**, 3.ª pessoa do singular do presente do conjuntivo do verbo **carregar**, que ocorre em expressões ofensivas como«(que vá para) o diabo que o/a carregue»; a forma não seria, portanto, adequada a um discurso isento de conotações vulgares (assinale-se que estas considerações constituem mera suposição, não encontrando apoio nas fontes consultadas).</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Carlos Rocha — 24 de janeiro de 2014
>
> ---

Answer (score 1):

Eu concordo com a resposta anterior, o particípio passado da maioria dos verbos é regular.
O particípio passado de alguns verbos é irregular, mas o verbo pagar aceita ambos os particípios; o particípio regular é usado somente em tempos compostos e o particípio irregular na voz passiva (ser, estar).

Pessoalmente, no exemplo que o senhor deu, eu diria "apesar de ter pago a conta" pois alem de "ter pagado" não me soar muito bem, "ter pago" enfatiza o facto de que a conta foi paga.
No entanto, em outros tempos compostos (pretérito mais-que-perfeito) já soa mais natural dizer "ele já tinha pagado", "já tinha aceitado" ou "já tinha gastado", mas também depende muito da nuance ou daquilo que se quer enfatizar.

Outros verbos deixam menos duvidas:
"ter morrido",
"ter expulsado",
"ter soltado",
"ter prendido"...

Ao passo que na voz passiva:
"foi pago",
"foi aceite",
"foi ganho",
"foi morto",
"foi expulso",
"foi solto",
"foi preso"...

Comment: Vocé não sabe instalar o teclado  internacional? Ou usar um formato com acentos? Porém, não é difícil.....existem várias soluções.

Comment: Tenho o teclado portugues instalado no computador, mas o teclado fisico eh japones... no celular so tenho ingles e japones.

Comment: @F.C. Creio que nos celulares atuais é fácil instalar um teclado de qualquer nacionalidade.