# "tem-me pagado" or "me tem pagado" or ...?

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, verbos, vocabulário, tempo-verbal

My question is only about Portuguese of Portugal.

I've done a search but barely found anything. What's the more correct, or more common, form among these:

- ele me tem pagado
- ele tem-me pagado
- ele tem pagado-me

The question isn't about "pagou"-form, but "pagado".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138372/discussion-on-question-by-kum-tem-me-pagado-or-me-tem-pagado-or).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second form is the one used and correct for European Portuguese, with a small change:

> Ele tem-me **pago**.

The form "pagado" has fallen in disuse in Portugal, see [Artefacto's good answer in a question about "pago vs pagado"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1403/157), complemented with Centaurus' answer for a solid understanding.

---

The first form, "ele me tem pagado", is Brasilian Portuguese - it uses *próclise* (me tem) where European Portuguese would use *ênclise* (tem-me).

The third form is incorrect, it's agrammatical.
I'm not 100% sure of this, but I think that the pronoun must always go with the auxiliary verb.
In this third form, it is wrongly with the main verb (*pagado-*me*).

Comment: @Schilive great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Portugal and in Brazil, the past participle should not have enclisis; in Portugal, it should neither have proclisis; then, the participle has no clitic pronoun. Basically, sentences as “Ele tem me visto” and “Tem pagado-me” are wrong.

But something can both be wrong and be used — figures of speech are actually intentional grammatical errors. In the [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), there are three *corpora*. Searching on the three by an example of a regular participle with an eclitic pronoun (e.g., *eu tenho pagado-te*), I found only a few examples. Most examples could be only an error, since the past participle and the gerund have a lot in common in Portuguese, and their writings are similar enough; for example, [here](https://www.jn.pt/mundo/representante-do-vaticano-em-franca-suspeito-de-agressao-sexual-10581508.html), with perhaps *torn**ado**-se* instead of *torn**ando**-se*.

But some even fewer examples were probably not a mistake, as on [here](https://zap.aeiou.pt/hitler-abracou-menina-judia-leilao-227288). These websites also had a more colloquial language.

Therefore, the forms «tem-me pagado» and «ele não me tem pagado» seem to be the most common. The rest, that is «tem me pagado»/«tem me-pagado» and «tem pagado-me», seem to be exceptional.

Comment: Alright, an answer. But you've done is some research and then have given me *your* conclusion based on it, as for what *seems* correct and incorrect *to you*. Right? How it really is, on practise you don't know, do you?

Comment: The form "me tem pagado" does not sound correct in the context of the question. "Ele me tem pagado" is incorrect for pt-PT. Can you include a complete example sentence for "me tem pagado" with your question? :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. :)

Comment: IIUC, even in Brazil proclisis to a participle requires another verb. So you can say _ele não tem me pagado as contas_, but not _uma vez me pagadas/pagas as contas, fiquei contente_.

Comment: @Artefacto, I personally think «uma vez pagas as contas, fiquei contente» is fine. It sound normal to me. But I think it is non-standard.