# O documento já foi impresso ou imprimido ? Qual a forma correcta?

Tags: ortografia, verbos, tempo-verbal

Diz-se: “o documento já foi impresso” ou “o documento já foi imprimido”?

Qual das duas é a forma correcta?
Impresso é um documento para preencher.

Comment: @CIMend Esta questão precisa de mais algum contexto. Relativamente à última frase desta questão “Impresso é um documento para preencher”, pode esclarecer onde está a dúvida? Qual foi o motivo para esse último comentário?

Comment: "Impresso" também é substantivo, me parece que é a essa acepção que o OP se refere na última frase. @Rye

Comment: A resposta mais simples, com a regra tradicional, é: com a voz passiva, com "ser", "estar", etc., se usa preferencialmente a forma irregular, "impresso", enquanto "imprimido" é usado com a voz ativa, com os verbos "ter" e "haver". Assim, a resposta é: "**impresso**". Cf. e.g. [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/imprimido-ou-impresso/338). Mas considero essa pergunta uma duplicada de uma já existente no site que, portanto, deve ser fechada.

Comment: Nao neste siteee

Comment: @ClMend Você não considera sua pergunta respondida [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/pago-ou-pagado)?